# Limit Model Schema navigation level in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

I am having problem with my Swagger cause it takes so much time to load. I have implemented navigation properties widely in the models of my project. After implementation of this, swagger has abruptly increased load time. It takes almost 5 minutes for my API with 50 controllers to load in Swagger UI. Let me know if there's any way to limit level of Model Schema navigation to be shown in Swagger UI or not to display navigation properties also.